# Android Calendar : Get day of next week

Tags: android, date

I have this method that parses a day and time, the problem is I need to get the day of next week.

Example:

I have this day and time **Monday, 10:00 PM** and the current time is **Monday, 11:00 PM**,

when I parse this `parseTime("M","10:00 PM")` it returns me the past date because of the current time.

I want to achieve is the next week's **Monday, 10:00 PM**

```
public static Calendar parseTime(String day, String time) {

    String[] sepa_time_ampm = time.split(" ");

    String[] sepa_time_hr_mn = sepa_time_ampm[0].split(":");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (!isNumeric(day)) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, parseDay(day));
    }

    if(Integer.parseInt(sepa_time_hr_mn[0]) == 12) sepa_time_hr_mn[0] = "00";

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(sepa_time_hr_mn[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sepa_time_hr_mn[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);



    if (sepa_time_ampm[1].equals("AM")) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    } else {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    }

    if((calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) < 0) {
    //It is now in the past
    }

    return calendar;

}
```

Comment: surely a simple test with the Date now will do.  If Date1 < now then add one week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- set Calendar to next week. This will set calendar to one week ahead.

  ```
  Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  int i = mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
  mCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, ++i);
  ```
- Then find days of next week easily

  ```
      /** Now get nExt week days **/
  int dayvalues=mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
  ```